# How to Retrieve Value from a php variable object

Tags: php, object, post

I have value returned in PHP `$_POST['upload-picture']` is

```
[{"file":"0:/desert.jpg"}]
```

I don't know how to retrieve the name of upload pictures from this format. I tried googling so many things but still didn't reach my destination.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: What have you tried? That looks like an array, containing a JSON structure

Comment: This is json data. so just json_decode it and you can use.

Comment: `$file = json_decode($_POST['upload-picture'][0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the data using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it to get the desired name:-

```
$image_array = json_decode($_POST['upload-picture'][0], true);

$final_image_name = explode('/',$image_array['file'])[1];

echo $final_image_name;
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1003521

Answer (score 1):

Assumming that `$data` has the values;

```
$data = [{"file":"0:/desert.jpg"}];
$array_data = json_decode($data[0], true);
echo $array_data['file'];  // This will print name of the image file.
```

Comment: That still won’t give the `name`. What is about the `0:/`.